# Spring data JPA with dynamic where clause

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a base Repository, say `IBaseRepository` which is

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity<PK>, PK extends Serializable>
      extends JpaRepository<T, PK>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>  {
}
```

now every repository class, for example `UserRepository` extends from this base repository. How can I add a general method like

```
T findOne(String filter, Map<String, Object> params);
```

for all inherited classes so that calling

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put("username","Lord");
params.put("locked",Status.LOCKED);
userRepo.findeOne("username = :username AND status = :locked",params);
```

return me a single record with dynamic where clause.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, you should use the JPA query for this.

Comment: You can't do that, the JPA queries are precompiled for performance reasons. If you want anything dynamic, you have to build a query yourself.

Comment: well, thank you guys. I thought so.

Comment: You can [create a custom repository implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).

Answer (score 2):

You can do the Following

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by shazi on 1/11/2017.
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IBaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    T findOne(String filter, Map<String, Object> params);

}
```

And Implement it as follows.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by shazi on 1/11/2017.
 */
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements IBaseRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private final JpaEntityInformation entityInformation;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation,
                            EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);

        // Keep the EntityManager around to used from the newly introduced methods.
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
    }

    @Override
    public T findOne(String filter, Map<String, Object> params) {
        final String jpql = "FROM " + entityInformation.getEntityName() + " WHERE " + filter;
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> value:params.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(value.getKey(), value.getValue());
        }
        return (T) query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

And configure it as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RepoConfig {
```

or in XML

```
<repositories base-class="….BaseRepositoryImpl" />
```

Finally you can use it as follows;

```
User found = userRepository.findOne("name = :name", Collections.singletonMap("name", "name"));
```

But you have to make sure that your query WHERE is such that the Query will always return 1 result only. See this [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/spring-data-jpa-with-dynamic-where.html)