# JPA with dynamic WHERE statement and handling JPA joins in MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have got 2 generic questions about setting up JPA  projects.

**Question 1:**
I need to be able to run queries based on different combinations of Table/Entity columns.

For example :
If a table has 10 columns. It means that there are  lots of possible combinations.
Should I need to write functions in my DAO and Service layer for each unique combination?
Is it possible to write a generic function to avoid having to compose lots of functions at DAO and Service Layer? How would I proceed?

**Question 2:**
I have 2 tables and corresponding DAOs and services.
If I will have to make 'Join queries' should I then make new DAO and Service for this join? Or can I just make a service and handle the querying directly in service instead of DAO using EntityManager ( like Session in hibernate)?

Lots of questions running in my mind but these two are most important for me, and will help my on my way.

Comment: Your question is bit too broad. If you have two questions ask two questions separately. Also try to give some more detailed example per question preferably with code and point where you have difficulties to proceed. Otherwise you might not get many answers or your question might even be removed.

Comment: Improved language and question

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: take a look here: [Spring data JPA with dynamic where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583419/spring-data-jpa-with-dynamic-where-clause)

Question 2: at one point, you need to choose how you want to represent the joined data. You could write a new class, and transform the joined data into it.

So table1: PhoneBookEntry, table2: Person, you join these and then turn it into a new object you will call ContactInfo, yourself.

```
public List<ContactData> getContacts(){
    ArrayList<ContactData> result = new ArrayList<ContactData>();

    List<Object[]> resultRows = em.createQuery("SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName, n.phoneNumber FROM Person p LEFT JOIN PhoneBookEntry n ON p.firstName = n.firstName AND p.lastName = n.lastName").getResultList();

    for (Object[] row : resultRows) {
        result.add(new ContactData(result[0], result[1], result[2]));
    }

    return result;
}
```